# What are the best practices for migrating an Oracle 10g database to Microsoft SQL 2008 R2? Application is using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, migration

Basically what the title says. Going forward, we need to start supporting both database platforms (and will start writing migrations accordingly), but we need to do the first initial "port".

Our DBAs are confident they can convert the schema, tables, data types, etc. but our developers have less confidence that the DAOs will "just work". Can someone point us towards some resources we can review? Ideally common pitfalls to avoid, specific tests to run, etc. We will of course run the full suite of database tests at the application layer, but want to do as much preparation as possible before then.

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to and test performance **under load**. Oracle does some things fundamentally differently than other database vendors. Tom Kyte's excellent book Expert Oracle Database Architecture points out several differences. A couple of highlights:

1. Oracle never locks data just to read it. Many other databases do.
2. A writer of data in Oracle never blocks a reader. A reader of data never blocks a writer. Again, many other vendors do.

Not paying attention to things like this can cause big headaches after a conversion when locking issues surface. This is not to imply a superiority of one product over another, rather it just means that what works well with one vendor's product may fail miserably in another, and custom approaches depending on the database may be required.

Comment: If you are moving to SQL Server 2008 R2 (or anything from 2005 on), ask your DBAs if it is possible to set up your databases using Read Committed Snapshot Isolation.  There are some caveats to this that hopefully your DBAs will know about.  But if it is possible it will provide the same transaction isolation level as Oracle, so that reads and updates don't block each other.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto (although on a quite simple schema, have to say). "Just worked". Hibernate magic.

I had my peace of mind because we had 100% test coverage for DAO layer. So when schema was recreated on MS SQL, and some table and column names were updated in the mapping (don't remember why, but DBAs asked to, may be naming convention), we just run our tests and found no failed ones.

P.S. Recalled one interesting detail: functional tests were all OK. But when PTE started on MS SQL database, we have found that a concurrent access to one particular table was times slower than on Oracle due to locks propagation. We had to redesign that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step would be to get an empty MS SQL schema, use `hbm2ddl=true` and let Hibernate create the tables there. Then show this to your DBAs and ask if this makes sense.

Populating data is less of a problem, I'd guess queries would be more slippery (especially if you use raw JDBC in some places). You might also want to check query plans for commonly used queries and see if these make sense, too.

Comment: Thanks but what about stored procedures? There are quite a few in use for performance reasons (e.g., calculating/storing huge sets of data without having to read in to memory at the DAO layer). These will need to be converted somehow from Oracle to MSSQL syntax I'd imagine?

Comment: I'd guess these would have to be rewritten and completely re-tested. I don't think Hibernate offers any help here, you'd have to do this by hand.