# Performance Testing Various Databases

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

I am currently testing a few different relational database management systems. (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and Firebird SQL) using a Java application to do so.

I was debating what tests I should run to distinguish the performances of each.

The obvious ones would be `insert`, `select`, `delete` and `drop`.

I would love to hear your opinions and to make this apply to the question answer format I shall ask for the 5 most appropriate tests to indicate performace differences. In an ideal world I would like to mimic real word use.

Thanks to all who answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that any of them would probably be fine.  However, your configuration of the different databases for what you are trying to do would be different based on your application.

Suggested place to start: look for apps similar to yours.  See what they are using, if you can.  Then start testing the different databases with similar configurations and see what works for you.

Personally I've used Oracle, MySql, and Postgres over the last 11 years and they've all worked well.  It's really all in your configuration, which is where a good DBA comes in handy.

Comment: Hi Alan, the purpose of the application is to apply the tests. The application simply allows creation of a connection and then manipulation of the database through user input with any reuslts output in the user interface. Thankyou for your comments. In fact I thank everyone for input this will help me to establish expected results. I am testing the RDBMS with the application running on varying O.S and the RDBMS on varying servers. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok in that case, then set up a baseline of tests you want to perform.  I'd say that anything that writes is going to take more resources than anything that reads, generally.  So use some insert and update queries.  Then use some selects.  These can be run in batches, probably with looping.  The important thing once you establish a baseline is to run the same set of queries on each DB.  AND make sure that your configurations on each DB are as close to equivalent as possible, to yield a valid result.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of input I was looking for thankyou! A couple of the links below should help me to establish some appropriate tests. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the results of a [fairly extensive benchmarks](http://www.jpab.org/Test_Description.html) of JPA providers and RDBMS's.  You can either use the data they provide, or you can [download their code](http://www.jpab.org/Download.html) and run it yourself.

Comment: Thankyou for your time. I believe this will certainly help me to structure my findings in a more appropriate manner.

Comment: @user671430 - glad you found this info useful.  Feel free to "accept" my answer if you believe if sufficiently resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Test concurrency. In other words, what happens under various locking scenarios? Ideally you would like to test under as close to real world conditions as possible, with multiple users using the system as it was meant to be used. See my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721987/what-are-the-best-practices-for-migrating-an-oracle-10g-database-to-microsoft-sql).

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time.